# Unable to add new color class to first sub - menu item when outer menu item is opened in accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

Here is my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/d3su54rt/2/

I have used accordion to implement a menu with sub-menus. What I am looking to do is that everytime an outer menu item is clicked, I want the first item (first child) to highlight to red even if it isnt clicked. And when I click on any other menu item, then it should highlight only the one clicked. And then when I open an outer menu item again, by default the first one should highlight again. I am trying to add a class innerMenuItemOnClick based on specific accordion open tab.

Here is my html:

```
 <div id="accordion">
    <h3 class="outerMenuItem">OuterItem1</h3>
    <ul id="statusId">
        <li><a class="innerMenuItem" href="#!">Inner Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a class="innerMenuItem" href="#!">Inner Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a class="innerMenuItem" href="#!">Inner Item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <h3 class="outerMenuItem">OuterItem2</h3>
    <ul id="networkId">
        <li><a class="innerMenuItem" href="#!">Inner Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a class="innerMenuItem" href="#!">Inner Item 2</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Here is my jquery:

```
$("#accordion").accordion({collapsible:true, active:0, heightStyle: "content"});


$(document).on("click",".outerMenuItem",function(){
    var currentlyActive=$( "#accordion" ).accordion( "option", "active" );
    console.log("Current tab no. "+currentlyActive);

    if(currentlyActive===0){   
        console.log($("#statusId li:first-child").text());
        $("#statusId li:first-child").addClass("innerMenuItemOnClick");          
    }

    else if(currentlyActive===1){
        $("#networkId li:first-child").addClass("innerMenuItemOnClick");

    }



    else {

        $("#protocolParameters").load("/404.html .someError");

    }

});

$(document).on("click",".innerMenuItem",function () {
    $(".innerMenuItem").removeClass("innerMenuItemOnClick");
    $(this).addClass("innerMenuItemOnClick");


});
```

Here is the underlying css:

```
 #accordion .ui-icon{
display:none;
 }

  #accordion .ui-accordion-header{
     height:30px;
     position: relative;
     z-index: 3;
     width:200px;

     }

     #accordion .ui-accordion-header:hover{
          color:#eb5e13;
      }

     #accordion .ui-accordion-header .ui-state-active{
      color:#eb5e13;
      }

     #accordion .ui-accordion-content {
       position: relative;
       z-index: 6;
       width:180px;
       color:#eb5e13;
     }

     #accordion .ui-accordion-header:active{
       color:#eb5e13;
     }

     a{
        color: #3f3f4e;
         font-weight: bold;
        padding-left:15px;
      }


      a.innerMenuItem{
         color: #363545;
       }

     a.innerMenuItemOnClick{
       color:#eb5e13 !important;
      }
```

Comment: I don't finish to understand your issue neither your code, but is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/d3su54rt/3/) what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes this is one part I want. However, what I want is that if I click on one of those "inner Menu Items" say item 2 then the one clicked should highlight and the first one should go back to original black font color. If you run my version you will see that you can click the menu items and they turn red when clicked. So what I want is combination of what you just showed and what I have earlier. Also, it would be nice if once the page loads, the first menu item is highlighted. Right now, your code doesnt do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the **innerMenuItemOnClick** class to the **li** tag, but your CSS is for **a.innerMenuItemOnClick**, which means it will only apply to an **a** tag with that class.

To be consistent with your use of this class on the **a** tag for the click handler on your innerMenuItem links, you should add "a" to your CSS selector, adding the class to the **a** tag directly:

```
   $("#statusId li:first-child a").addClass("innerMenuItemOnClick");
```

This requires a change to the outerMenuItem handler to remove the style on a previously clicked innerMenuItem.  I simply added this to the top of that handler:

```
$(".innerMenuItem").removeClass("innerMenuItemOnClick");
```

Here is an update to your fiddle this two line change:

https://jsfiddle.net/5rhnyyfe/

Comment: Your method works for the first case where the first sub menu item should highlight upon opening an accordion. However, if i click on the sibling sub menu item say item 2 it doesnt let me highlight it. If you check my version initially, it was doing that. Any way around to fix this? And please share your updated fiddle too. Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris. It would have taken so long to figure this one out. You saved my day